# Compilation Issues building Nativescript app after upgrade to NS 7.0.6

Tags: nativescript

After a long time, I have upgraded my Nativescript app which was running fine on NS version 5. After upgraded to NS 7.0.6 through NS version 6, I started getting following errors coming from the plugin dependencies. Please note I have tried deleting the node_modules, hooks and platform folders.

```
node_modules/@nativescript/core/global-types.d.ts:1:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: "audio", "beacon", "cspreport", "download", "embed", "eventsource", "favicon", "fetch", "font", "form", "frame", "hyperlink", "iframe", "image", "imageset", "import", "internal", "location", "manifest", "object", "ping", "plugin", "prefetch", "script", "serviceworker", "sharedworker", "subresource", "style", "track", "video", "worker", "xmlhttprequest", "xslt", HeaderInit, WeakRef

1 declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis;
  ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/@nativescript/core/tns-core-modules.d.ts:4:1
    4 declare enum RequestContext {
      ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

node_modules/@nativescript/core/global-types.d.ts:136:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ModuleType'.

136 declare type ModuleType = 'markup' | 'script' | 'style';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/@nativescript/core/module.d.ts:95:14
    95 declare type ModuleType = "markup" | "script" | "style";
                    ~~~~~~~~~~
    'ModuleType' was also declared here.

node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/@nativescript/core/module.d.ts:2:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'global' must be of type 'Global & typeof globalThis', but here has type 'Global'.

2 declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
              ~~~~~~

  node_modules/@nativescript/core/global-types.d.ts:1:13
    1 declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis;
                  ~~~~~~
    'global' was also declared here.

node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/@nativescript/core/module.d.ts:95:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ModuleType'.

95 declare type ModuleType = "markup" | "script" | "style";
                ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@nativescript/core/global-types.d.ts:136:14
    136 declare type ModuleType = 'markup' | 'script' | 'style';
                     ~~~~~~~~~~
    'ModuleType' was also declared here.

node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/@nativescript/core/tns-core-modules.d.ts:4:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: "audio", "beacon", "cspreport", "download", "embed", "eventsource", "favicon", "fetch", "font", "form", "frame", "hyperlink", "iframe", "image", "imageset", "import", "internal", "location", "manifest", "object", "ping", "plugin", "prefetch", "script", "serviceworker", "sharedworker", "subresource", "style", "track", "video", "worker", "xmlhttprequest", "xslt", HeaderInit, WeakRef

4 declare enum RequestContext {
  ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@nativescript/core/global-types.d.ts:1:1
    1 declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis;
      ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

node_modules/tns-core-modules/node_modules/@nativescript/core/tns-core-modules.d.ts:5:5 - error TS2432: In an enum with multiple declarations, only one declaration can omit an initializer for its first enum element.

5     "audio", "beacon", "cspreport", "download", "embed", "eventsource", "favicon", "fetch",
      ~~~~~~~
Found 6 errors.
```

Following are my plugin dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@nativescript/core": "~7.0.11",
  "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
  "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.4",
  "nativescript-grid-view": "^5.1.0",
  "nativescript-purchase": "^2.0.14",
  "nativescript-screen-orientation": "^2.0.0",
  "nativescript-social-share-ns-7": "^11.6.0",
  "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
  "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
  "nativescript-ui-chart": "8.0.2",
  "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "9.0.3",
  "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "0.7.0",
  "rxjs": "~6.6.3"
}
```

Since this is part of plugin, I am not sure how I can have these fixed? Any help is highly appreciated. Please let me know in case you need any other details.

Comment: you have to check/update plugins too, such as @nativescript/appversion 
 in stead of nativescript-appversion. Check https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-compatible-plugins/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The error looks like coming from nativescript/core and tns-core-modules which are at the latest versions. Even after upgrade, the 6 error stay as it is.

Comment: In NS 7, You have to remove all occurrences of tns-core-modules, https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-for-plugin-authors/

Comment: That link was really helpful! Thank you !